# Add default whitespace between two <input> elements

Tags: javascript, css, forms, whitespace

I'm working with HTML generated by a CMS.

HTML generated is as follows

```
<input id="something" type="text"><input type="submit" value="Search">
```

instead of

```
<input id="something" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
```

which causes this:

[image]

instead of the default:

[image]

Is there a way I can either via CSS or javascript add the default white space between all my input/form elements?

Would prefer if it was YUI or plain javascript.

Thanks!

EDIT: I dont want to just add a margin because some input elememts DO have the default whitespace. It is only come code which are output without it. Srry!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qfJPs/1/

Comment: It is not the same question :( They are rather different.

Comment: thanks serge, but I cannot alter the HTML :(

Comment: but you have changed the HTML :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be working for me:

```
$('input').after(" ");
```

Comment: thank you for all the help, i will remember the negative margin also in the future!

Answer (score -1):

You need put a margin

```
 #something{margin-right:15px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid doing it that way and learn more about CSS strategies like: [margin and padding](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

Answer (score -1):

Just add a `margin-right` to all of your text inputs

http://jsfiddle.net/weissman258/2NSZJ/

Comment: I want to add the default whitespace, a margin won't be the solution :(